# jQuery and operation in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have two input text and i want use jquery to do an operation with them. The input text are this:

```
<p>
    <label>Title 1</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field2" class="width100" value="<?php echo $field1t; ?>"  />
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Title 2</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" class="width100" value="<?php echo $field2t ?>"  />
    </span>
</p>
```

I would like to enter a number in the first input and, in real time, this number should be entered in the second input

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event on the `#field1` textbox.

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <label>Title 1</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" class="width100" value="<?php echo $field1t; ?>"  />
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Title 2</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" class="width100" value="<?php echo $field2t ?>"  />
    </span>
</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
// On every keyup of textbox
$('#field1').on('keyup', function () {
    $('#field2').val($(this).val());
    // Set the text in field1 into field2
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nrcmbr07/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/w4bmzmra/).

```
$('#field1').keyup(function() {        
    var selThisVal = $(this).val();
    $('#field2').val(selThisVal);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Both input can not have same `id's`. `ID's should be unique`.
you can use `.change` or `.keyup` event to change the second input value.

Using `.change`

```js
$('input[name="field1"]').change(function(){
    $('input[name="field2"]').val($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label>Title 1</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field2" class="width100" value="<?php echo $field1t; ?>"  />
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Title 2</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" class="width100" value="<?php echo $field2t ?>"  />
    </span>
</p>
```

Using `.kepup`

```js
$('input[name="field1"]').keyup(function(){
    $('input[name="field2"]').val($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label>Title 1</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field2" class="width100" value="<?php echo $field1t; ?>"  />
    </span>
</p>
<p>
    <label>Title 2</label>
    <span class="field">
        <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" class="width100" value="<?php echo $field2t ?>"  />
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `input` event to synchronise the contents. The `input` event get's raised every time the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element get's changed by the user (not by code). This is in your case a little bit better over the `keyup` event, since it ignores stuff like left arrow hits etc and only get's raised if the value actually changes. To use it with `jQuery`:

```js
$('#field1').on("input", function(){
    $('#field2').val($('#field1').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <input id="field1" />
</p>
<p>
    <input id="field2" />
</p>
```

or pure js:

```js
document.getElementById("field1").oninput = function(){
    document.getElementById("field2").value = this.value;    
};
```

```html
<p>
    <input id="field1" />
</p>
<p>
    <input id="field2" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First update id of first textbox to `field1`, Right now you have same id for both textbox.

Then try given script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#field1").keyup(function(){
            $("#field2").val($("#field1").val());
        });
    })
</script>
```